# How to archive diff files between two commit with jgit?

Tags: java, jgit

I'm trying to create an archive between two commits on my branch,but have no idea..

here's my code:

```
ArchiveCommand.registerFormat("zip", new ZipArchiveFormat());                 
git.archive()
.setTree(repo.resolve("refs/heads/master^{tree}"))
.setFormat("zip")
.setOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("test.zip")))
.call();
```

I use git command like this git archive --output=files.tar HEAD $(git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT 809365fe 7793cf5) how can I do this command with jGit?

thanks for every reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot archive diffs, neither with Git nor with JGit. An archive is always created from a tree.

Comment: I use git command like this `git archive --output=files.tar HEAD $(git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT 809365fe  7793cf5)`

how can I do this command with jGit? thank you

Comment: In order to get an answer, you should edit the question with these requirements